# Why does the official LibAV 12 video example not work properly?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encode, libav

I would say the title is quite self-explanatory, but I nearly completely copied the example given by LibAV right [here](https://libav.org/documentation/doxygen/master/encode_video_8c-example.html) and yet the output video it produced was not playable. Why is it not playable? Am I using the wrong file extension? I do not understand what I could have possibly done wrong here and there's little to no documentation I could find for how to encode mp4 video in C++.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libavutil/frame.h"
#include "libavutil/imgutils.h"

static void encode(AVCodecContext *enc_ctx, AVFrame *frame, AVPacket *pkt, FILE *outfile) {
    int ret;
    ret = avcodec_send_frame(enc_ctx, frame);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error sending a frame for encoding\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (ret >= 0) {
        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(enc_ctx, pkt);
        if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
            return;
        else if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error during encoding\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("encoded frame %3"PRId64" (size=%5d)\n", pkt->pts, pkt->size);
        fwrite(pkt->data, 1, pkt->size, outfile);
        av_packet_unref(pkt);
    }
}

int main() {
    const char *filename = "animation.mp4";
    const AVCodec *codec;
    AVCodecContext *c = NULL;
    int i, ret, x, y;
    FILE *f;
    AVFrame *picture;
    AVPacket *pkt;
    uint8_t endcode[] = { 0, 0, 1, 0xb7 };
    if (argc <= 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <output file>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    avcodec_register_all();
    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO);
    if (!codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "codec not found\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    picture = av_frame_alloc();
    pkt = av_packet_alloc();
    if (!pkt)
        exit(1);
    c->bit_rate = 400000;
    c->width = 352;
    c->height = 288;
    c->time_base = (AVRational){1, 25};
    c->framerate = (AVRational){25, 1};
    c->gop_size = 10;
    c->max_b_frames=1;
    c->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    if (avcodec_open2(c, codec, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not open codec\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    f = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (!f) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not open %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    picture->format = c->pix_fmt;
    picture->width  = c->width;
    picture->height = c->height;
    ret = av_frame_get_buffer(picture, 32);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not alloc the frame data\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(i=0;i<25;i++) {
        fflush(stdout);
        ret = av_frame_make_writable(picture);
        if (ret < 0)
            exit(1);

        for(y=0;y<c->height;y++) {
            for(x=0;x<c->width;x++) {
                picture->data[0][y * picture->linesize[0] + x] = x + y + i * 3;
            }
        }

        for(y=0;y<c->height/2;y++) {
            for(x=0;x<c->width/2;x++) {
                picture->data[1][y * picture->linesize[1] + x] = 128 + y + i * 2;
                picture->data[2][y * picture->linesize[2] + x] = 64 + x + i * 5;
            }
        }

        picture->pts = i;
        encode(c, picture, pkt, f);
    }

    encode(c, NULL, pkt, f);

    fwrite(endcode, 1, sizeof(endcode), f);
    fclose(f);
    avcodec_free_context(&c);
    av_frame_free(&picture);
    av_packet_free(&pkt);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Libav is dead. Try FFmpeg.

Comment: i switched to FFmpeg and I can encode and mux mp4 files now, thanks!